# Remove Ubuntu 22.04 LTS dock border

Tags: gnome, 22.04, customization, dock

Is there a way to remove the border from the dock? (please see image reference)

[image]

I tried with gsettings but didn't find any key or value that refers to that specific border. Any guess?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably some cascade style sheet code hidden somewhere in the system files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was bugging me too. I was able to remove by doing this:

- Install this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5004/dash-to-dock-for-cosmic/
- Disable the default Ubuntu Dock on the extensions app.
- Go to the settings of Dash To Dock for COSMIC from the extensions app.
- On the appearance tab, Customize the dash color and select black.
- Set the opacity as you prefer.

The border is gone.