# Cannot change opacity of Dock in 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, dock, dconf, dash-to-dock

I'd like my Dock to have no transparency at all.

I've tried to modify the opacity of the Dock with dconf-Editor (https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-customize-dock-panel-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux) but it has no effect.

The following command has no effect too:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock background-opacity 1.0
```

Comment: you have dash-to-dock installed and enabled, I assume?

Comment: I had Dash to Dock from michele_g in some previous versions of Ubuntu. I think it is not installed on my machine anymore and it seems to be unsupported on Gnome 42 anyway. What I have is Ubuntu Dock. I think this is Dash to Dock which has been integrated to the Ubuntu distribution. However, I'm always lost when dealing with Linux packages, so maybe it is not how it works... Anyway, on Ubuntu 21.10, I had Ubuntu Dock installed and didn't have Dash to Dock and was able to change opacity using dconf-Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dconf-Editor, changing the *transparency-mode* from 'DEFAULT' to 'FIXED' solved the problem.

Comment: Did not work for me, and this is dconf-Editor's description: "FIXED: constant transparency. DYNAMIC: dock takes the opaque style only when windows are close to it."  Dynamic also did not work for me. Changing dash opacity did, though.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works with this Gnome Extension:
**[Remove Ubuntu 22.04 LTS dock border](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409684/remove-ubuntu-22-04-lts-dock-border)**

And the Dock is very customizable too!

Answer (score 0):

Open dconf-Editor, find dash-to-dock, change dash's background-opacity to 1.

This is the change that finally worked for me but I did click a bunch of other settings in dash-to-dock first, so I can't swear it wasn't a combination of things. I do also have to set the dock's transparency-mode to FIXED to make it work, as TVG mentions.